# How to change color of font awesome icon

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a `font-awesome` icon I'd like to change to `white`.

How do I do this? here is my css.

```
.phone {
     font-size: 15px;color: 
     #ffffff! Important;
}
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: share your code here.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Are you targeting the correct class, as it should be `fa-phone` for example.

Comment: It won't let me edit question. Here is html:
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/"><div class="email"><span><center><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></center></span></div></a><a href="tel:<br/><label>Phone:</label> 07576xxxxx"><div class="phone"><span><center><span class="fas fa-phone"</span></center></span></div></a>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=:<br/><label>Location:</label> Westminster, London, UK"><div class="location"><span><center><span class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"</span></center></span></div></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to target the right class

```
 .fa-phone {font-size: 15px;color:#ffffff! Important;}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
.icon {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon i {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="icon">
  <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</div>
```